# What algorithm could we best use here?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, python, predictive-models

For a coding course we're having an assignment which consists of predicting fire. The goal is, to predict the number of fires for an area, based on demographics.

The data we have consists of:
 - Number of fires in area
 - Percentage of women in an area
 - Percentage of men in an area
 - Percentage of single households
 - Percentage of more person households
 - Percentage of age-groups (0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, etc until 95+)

What we are trying to find is a correlation between the number of fires, and the demographic properties. So that we can predict the next number of fires, based on new demographics.

What Python algorithm could we best use for this?
So far we've tried 'Linear Regression', but this was not satisfactory, because we could only examine the influence of one single feature. Though we want to compare ***all*** these features.

*Note:
We don't expect a ready made answer, but some guidance on what algorithm we could best use. Our teacher is not available for a few weeks, and we would really like to get on with our assignment.*

*Also note that it is a requirement that we use python for this*

Comment: If I had to do it, I would use a random forest.  I use 'R' though, and some folks will take umbrage at the "particular package".  You might rephrase it as "I prefer python, but I'm just looking for a general approach.  Is this a public dataset?  What kind of fire?  Here is a public and published form that you might compare your numeric results to: https://www.usfa.fema.gov/downloads/pdf/statistics/v14i8.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I personally would prefer to try out some different languages, though school requires python. The dataset itself is closed sadly. What we strictly have, is just the number of fires, measured in a specific area. (e.g. `area 1: 14; area 2: 28`).
The dataset could in some way be compared to the you posted indeed. I'm gonna look into the random forest and see where it leads us!

Comment: You might want to put the self-study tag.  We can work it through here, and then you can put an answer here.  What are your column names and types.  How many rows do you have?  Are they wanting you to show methods you learned in lecture?  Lets make a proxy-problem and work through it.  note:Teachers find it funny (amazing) when you find their sources and can compare your step-by-step documented results with peer-reviewed, published results.

Comment: Hi, I've included these names in the comments. If I'm not mistaken, this should be  the code for it?

Comment: We did learn some about random forest in the lessons, so this should apply. If have about 28 rows of data at the moment. Fiddle I used for the pseudo solution: http://pythonfiddle.com/random-forest-_-cv

Comment: can't read the fiddle link.  Can you double-check that it was entered properly?